# NextJS - Haveibeenpwned API Fetch error 401

Tags: typescript, api, next.js

I'm using a valid key that I paid for, yet I keep getting a 401 when trying to fetch? What am I missing here?

```
const checkCompromised = async (email: string) => {
    const secret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HAVEIBEENPWNED_API_KEY;
    const url = `https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/${email}`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "hibp-api-key": `${secret}`,
        "User-Agent": "test",
      },
    });
    const data = await response.text();
    setCompromisedList(data);
  };
```

I think I'm following the documentation correctly...? https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#Authorisation
Has anybody here used HIBP API before? Any ideas?

Comment: `mode: "no-cors",` is a red flag. Node.js' fetch implementation has no reason to implement CORS. You tagged this [tag:next.js] which is a React (client-side) framework with server-side rendering features: Are you trying to run this in the server-side or browser-side code?

Comment: It throws the same error without it. My bad, I shouldn't have included it in the snippet-- I was just desperate and trying everything. But yeah I'm running this server-side.

Comment: I suggest creating the object you pass as the second argument to `fetch` *before* the function call and storing it in a variable. The logging it to make sure that the headers are correct. (i.e. `const options = { method... }; console.log(options); const response = await fetch(url, options);`. Also double check that the logs come out on the Node.js console and not the browser console.

Comment: ```headers
: 
User-Agent
: 
"test"
hibp-api-key
: [the right api key I got from the API website] as a string ``` Do you think this is an ssr thing?

Comment: I shouldn't think so. That looks (based on the documentation) like it should work if run in SSR.

Comment: Thank you. I reached out to them but it seems like the whole thing is just one dude, and I don't think I'm going to get an answer anytime soon. Oh well... I'll look for other API options.